# How can I transform null data in Algolia widget?

Tags: algolia

I am using Algolia instant search for listing my products.  I have the following widget to list items by language:

```js
search.addWidget(
  instantsearch.widgets.refinementList({
    container: '#language',
    attributeName: 'language',
    limit: 8,
    showMore: true,
    sortBy: ['isRefined', 'count:desc', 'name:asc'],
    operator: 'or',
    templates: {
      header: '<h4>Language</h4>',
    },
    cssClasses: {
      label: 'widget-label',
      checkbox: 'widget-checkbox',
    },
    transformData: function(item) {
      console.log(item);
      if(item.name == "Unspecified" || item.name == undefined){
        item.name = "Unspecified";
      }else{
        item.name = item.name;
      }
      return item;
    },
  })
);
```

I used to be able to transform any result where the item name (language) was null in the index.  But at some point that stopped working and I'm not sure what changed to make this happen.  I see the result data coming back with `"language":null` but my transformData no longer captures it.  I've tried `== NULL`, etc.  The desired results would be for an "Unspecified" option to also appear in the Language list for this widget.  Any suggestions?  Thanks in advance!

**Update:** 
It looks like the reason I used to get this to work was because our initial index import had NULL data in quotes.  My question still stands however - can I catch all items with a null value and transform those to display as an "Unspecified" item in the widget list?

Comment: If the data is `"NULL"`, can you edit your check to add `|| item.name === "NULL"`? Otherwise I think you'll have to manually write a script that pulls all data, edit `"NULL"` to undefined and push it again.

Comment: thank you @HaroenViaene.  I've also found the need to add `item.highlighted = "Unspecified";` to my code to catch data that was assigned "NULL" values (with quotes).